# Where is the default .NET Core SDK path in MacOS

Tags: macos, .net-core, rider

I've recently installed the .NET Core SDK for MacOS in order to create a demo application using the new JetBrains Rider EAP.

```
Project 'WebApi' load failed
Can't initialize DotNetCore: Please select  DotNet Core SDK path.
To get instructions how to setup visit https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core
```

After the installation I tried to find the path to the DotNet Core SDK without success.

Any idea about the location of the .NET Core SDK?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this path: `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`

It took some time to find it:

```
find / -name dotnet
```

Comment: Now it's `/usr/local/share/dotnet/x64/dotnet`

Answer (score 7):

If you run this in your terminal, it will list the installed SDK's and their locations. I believe it works in windows as well

```
dotnet --list-sdks
```

Comment: This command doesn't work even when the .Net framework has been installed

Comment: This is just for dotnet core

Answer (score 6):

For me it was:

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Users/$USER/.dotnet
```

Also, tips, if you run `find / -name dotnet` do it like:

```
find / -name dotnet 2>/dev/null
```

That way you don't get any permissions errors just real hits.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac (Ventura) and downloading the .NET SDK Arm64 instead of the .NET SDK 64x package worked for me.

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/sdk-for-vs-code?utm_source=vs-code&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=sdk-install